# How to access Parallels guest network services in a shared network virtual machine running in Mac OSX?

Tags: windows, macos, networking, iis, parallels

I have a Windows virtual machine running inside Parallels in my Mac OSX.

This virtual machine is setup to use shared network.

What I want is: How to access a IIS service running inside this virtual machine from other computers in the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Parallels preferences, open the Network section and set up a forwarded port.  You'll probably want to forward ports 80 and 443 to the VM's ports 80 and 443.